# es6 importing a class in a class

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, es6-class

in index.js I have.

```
import  PageLoader from './pageLoader';
$(function() {
  const pageLoader = new PageLoader();
});
```

and pageloader.js

```
class PageLoader{
   constructor(){
    {
       this.customer = null;
       this.data = [];
       this.init();
    }  
   } 
    init() { }
 }
module.exports = PageLoader;
```

everything works fine. but if I import a class from page loader.

```
import  Customer from './customer';
class PageLoader{
   constructor(){
    {
       this.customer = null;
       this.data = [];
       this.init();
    }  
   } 
    init() { }
 }
module.exports = PageLoader;
```

and customer.js

```
class Customer{
    constructor(){
       this.data = [];
       this.init();
    } 
    init() { 

    }
 }
 module.exports = Customer;
```

I receive

> WARNING in ./src/index.js 10:23-33 "export 'default' (imported as
>   'PageLoader') was not found in './pageLoader'

Comment: Why are you importing a class and never using it?

Comment: I am using it just did not want to muddle up the example with extra code

Comment: OK but it's just a warning - does the code actually work?

Comment: no it does not.

Comment: you're mixing commonjs and es6 modules. modules.export is from commonjs (nodejs) and import is from es6 modules (es6 js)

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `import {Pageloader} ...` with brackets?

Comment: And then `export class ...` like Gonzalo says...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
module.exports
```

syntax is from [Modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) (which are largely used in NodeJs - the counterpart of it is `require` rather than import). If you want to use `import`, you need to use `export` clause, which is from [es6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

```
export default PageLoader
```

you could also do named exports

```
export { PageLoader };
```

and then

```
import { PageLoader } from './pageLoader';
```

[Further reading](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910)